# Missing value with Order by Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have some records: vu, vunh, vu123,vu12. I'm trying to do natural sort with expected output like this:

> vu, vunh, vu12, vu123

here is my query:

```
select "firstName" from organization_users where "organizationId"='23' order by substr("firstName",0,char_length("firstName")-char_length(array_to_string(regexp_matches("firstName",'(\d+)'),''))+1),CAST( array_to_string(regexp_matches("firstName",'(\d+)'),'') AS INTEGER);
```

But I get output:

> vu12, vu123

only. I found out that is something wrong with records without numeric part. Anyone know why and how to solved it?

Ps: I do natural sort by devide them into 2 parts: alphabetical and numeric, then order by.

Edit 1: I wonder somehow if there is a way to set if numeric part is missing, there will be a default value equal 0? Or default value if regexp_matches() failed?

Comment: What does `select * from organization_users where "organizationId"='23'`  produce? You example is most easily explained by the fact those other rows don't match your selection criteria.

Comment: It produces list of user whose firstname as given

Comment: You mean all 4 names, not just the two??

Comment: yes, all 4 names

Comment: I think you need to step back and look at some other factors as there is no way the order by should affect the number of rows returned. How are you running this query? I assume the values are coming back as 4 rows rather than comma delimited?

Comment: yeah, it returns with 4 rows.

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid having a set returning function in the Order By clause.

Use `regex_match` instead

```
select "firstName" from organization_users 
order by substr("firstName",0,char_length("firstName")-char_length(array_to_string(regexp_match("firstName",'(\d+)'),''))+1),CAST( array_to_string(regexp_match("firstName",'(\d+)'),'') AS INTEGER);
 firstName
-----------
 vu12
 vu123
 vu
 vunh
```

That being said, you could simplify the entire query. Extract only the non-digits (`\D+`) or only the digits (`\d+`)

```
select "firstName" 
from organization_users 
order by  substring("firstName", '(\D+)'),substring("firstName", '(\d+)')  NULLS FIRST;
 firstName
-----------
 vu
 vu12
 vu123
 vunh
(4 rows)
```